Expressing a difference of powers with different exponents
I would like to express x2y2 - x1y1 as some function of Δx and Δy, where Δx = x2 - x1, Δy = y2 - y1, and y1 ≠ y2.
Thank you to those who have responded so far.  To clarify (hopefully!), I am trying to do something analogous to this: x2y2 - x1y1 = Δx$\overline{y}$ + Δy$\overline{x}$, where $\overline{z}$ = (z1 + z2) / 2, z = x, y.
As for what I have tried so far, beyond trying to use a logarithm to bring down the exponents, I haven't made any progress.  Thanks again.
As I have been asked for background information, motivation, etc... I plan on using this information to address a specific case of an accounting topic called "variance analysis (VA)."  The analogous example I added above is a two-variable product  VA example. If revenue (i.e., unit price multiplied by number of units sold) increases from one period to the next, what amount of that increase is attributed to each of the two variables that make up the product?  As for my specific question on this page, the answer will help me address a similar VA example: cost modeled as number of units sold (a variable) raised to some exponent between 1.8 and 2.2 (the second variable), evaluated at two points in time.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

This won't be sufficient.  At the very least, $x_1$ or $x_2$ must also be supplied to the function.  Going from four unknowns to two unknowns is ... unlikely.

You can't.  Your initial expression has four inputs.  You are trying to replace it with only two inputs.  Compute $8^6-5^4$ and $5^3-2^1$.  If you only supply the two differences, these two need to be equal.

@RossMillikan, thanks for the quick response.  Please see my modification above.

@EricTowers, thanks for the quick response. Please see my modification above.

The expression you give as a clarification is only valid when the changes in $x$ and $y$ are very small.  You did not describe this in the original post.  Because exponentials are so much more sensitive the similar expression will not be valid over even a similar range.

@RossMillikan : I get that the example is an identity; why do you interpret it as a small displacement approximation?

I assume you don't want to use the Gauss hypergeometric function in the answer?

Because you get it by taking the derivative with respect to $x$ and $y$ and assuming the other one stays fixed.  That is why you are using $\overline x$ and $\overline y$ in the formula.  If you look at how that formula works out when $x_1$ and $x_2$ are quite different and also $y_1$ and $y_2$ it doesn't work well.  It is even worse with exponentials.

@EricTowers: I am not familiar with the function you mentioned, but if that's what it takes...

@RossMillikan: I did not end up with the example solution by taking a derivative.  I only used algebra.  If you expand the RHS using the given definitions of average and difference, you will find the RHS equals the LHS side exactly.
